# Assumed existence of an intermediate set given $A \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I know that there are two sets, $A$ and $B$, such that $B \subseteq A$, can I assume for a proof that there is a $C$ such that $B \subseteq C \subseteq A$ since either $A = B = C$, $B = C \subset A$, $B \subset C = A$, or that there exists a $C$ such that $B \subset C \subset A$?

Comment: If $\subseteq$, obviously yes : $C=A$ or $C=B$ will do.

Comment: $C=B$ or $C=A$ always works.

Comment: If $\subset$, not necessarily. A set $\{ a \}$ with a single element (*singleton*) has only two subsets : $\emptyset$ and $\{ a \}$ itself.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The thing is, while I know that $A \subseteq B$, I need to apply a function to each that doesn't necessarily preserve the equality. It turned out that if I take $C = A$ it works, but I wasn't sure before and needed the possibility of an intermediate set.